# Android tabs not working properly C#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, tabs

So I've been stuck for a while now trying to implement a pair of tabs into my project. I've read quite a bit on how to do it and I'm not sure why it's not working. Can anybody tell me what am I doing wrong? Here's my .cs

```
public class TabActivity1 : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView textview = new TextView(this);
        textview.Text = "Tab 1";
        SetContentView(textview);
    }
}

public class TabActivity2 : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView textview = new TextView(this);
        textview.Text = "Tab 2";
        SetContentView(textview);
    }
}


public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        TabHost tab_host = FindViewById<TabHost>(Resource.Id.tabHost);
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;
        Intent intent;

        intent = new Intent(this, typeof(TabActivity1));
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
        spec = tab_host.NewTabSpec("Tab 1");
        spec.SetIndicator("tab1");
        spec.SetContent(intent);
        tab_host.AddTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent(this, typeof(TabActivity2));
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
        spec = tab_host.NewTabSpec("Tab 2");
        spec.SetIndicator("tab2");
        spec.SetContent(intent);
        tab_host.AddTab(spec);
    }
}
```

here's the .axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px">
<TabHost
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tabHost">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NAjU.jpg)'s what the app outputs.

I would really appreciate any help I can get, thank you!

Comment: So, what's the expected output? It's quite tiresome to guess the wanted outcome just by looking at the code.

Comment: I was hoping for 2 tabs labeled tab 1 and tab 2, and withing each tab a text box that says tab 1 within tab 1 and tab 2 within tab 2. What do you think I can do to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after some researching I found out that the Activity TabActivity  is deprecated, so I have to find another way to implement tabs, such as page sliders or sliding tabs.